# How to define Content Group in GA4 with Javascript (ie: using gtag instead of Tag Manager)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I'm migrating from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4. We don't use Google Tag Manager, we directly inject scripts on our web pages.

As suggested in migration guides, I integrated the GA4 script next to the UA script. Both tracking should work in parallel.

Here is the Javascript code. It includes some variables computed server-side (`content_group` and `dimensions`.

In UA, content group and custom dimensions are correctly defined.
In GA4, custom dimensions are correctly passed but but content group is marked as **(not set)**

Here is the code I include in every web page.

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) - GA4 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-VPPGG41SM8"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-VPPGG41SM8');
  gtag('set', 'content_group', '<%= content_group %>'); // Defined server-side with some business logic

  gtag('set', 'user_properties', {
    'client_type': "<%= dimensions.client_type %>", // same here
    'subscription_type': "<%= dimensions.subscription_type %>", // same here
    'mrr': "<%= dimensions.mrr %>", // same here
    'lifetime_value': "<%= dimensions.lifetime_value %>", // same here
  });
</script>

<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) - Universal Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-45949596-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-45949596-1', {
    'optimize_id': 'GTM-WG8W868',
    'content_group1':  "<%= content_group %>",
    'content_group2':  "<%= content_group_2 %>",
    'custom_map': {
      'dimension1': 'client_type',
      'dimension2': 'subscription_type',
      'dimension3': 'mrr',
      'dimension4': 'lifetime_value',
    },
  });
  gtag('set', {
    'content_group1': "<%= content_group %>",
    'content_group2': "<%= content_group_2 %>",
    'dimension1': "<%= dimensions.client_type %>",
    'dimension2': "<%= dimensions.subscription_type %>",
    'dimension3': "<%= dimensions.mrr %>",
    'dimension4': "<%= dimensions.lifetime_value %>",
  });
</script>
```

On GA4, when I display numbers based on content group:

[image: not set content group]

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Side note GTM is great you should try it.   makes testing easer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news, since GA4 you can't use more than one `content_group`.

Also `content_group` must be set using `config`, you should do you something like this:

```
gtag('config', 'G-KEYVALUE', {
    'content_group': 'ONLY_ONE_VALUE'
});
```

Comment: Nice, thank you GBS!

It's a pity the GA4 doc suggests another solution (that doesn't work). Cfr: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11523339?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgoogle-tag-websites